# Is it Blueprint CSS framework out of date?

Tags: css, blueprint-css

I want to use blueprint css framework but last version release was over year ago. Neither commits in Github repository. Has it being mantained?

Comment: I think you should be asking this question on Blueprint's Facebook or Twitter.

Comment: I think you've answered your own question.  All signs point to it being inactive since ~May 2011.  The Latest stable version should still work, but it doesn't appear to be under development.

Comment: If you need something similar that is being maintained, have a look at Twitter's Bootstrap: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html

Comment: ...Another year+ later and nothing has been touched, including their Twitter feed and Facebook page.

Answer (score 1):

Blueprint it's outdated.

Try this ones:

- http://getbootstrap.com/
- http://foundation.zurb.com/
- http://semantic-ui.com/